# Proof of theorem 6.6 in Functional Analysis of Haim Brezis (Fredholm alternative)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

I'm reading the proof of the following theorem:
[image: Teorem]

My question is in part d), the last paragraph says that:
[image: Proof]

I'm not sure why
$$
N(I-T) \subseteq N(I-T^{**})
$$
because
$$
N(I-T) \subseteq E \quad\mbox{and}\quad N(I-T^{**})\subseteq E''
$$

Comment: There exists a canonical injection $J : E \to E^{**}$ that Brezis defines in chapter 1. We are actually saying $J(N(I - T)) \subset N(I - T^{**}).$

Comment: I assume $E$ here is a Hilbert space?  In that case $E$ is canonically isomorphic to $E''$.  Strictly speaking it is not the case that $N(I-T) \subseteq N(I-T^{**})$, but rather that the image of $N(I-T)$ is a subset of $N(I-T^{**})$ under this isomorphism.  Very often, however, $E$ and $E''$ are just identified through this isomorphism, which seems to be what is happening here.

Comment: @Chris It's not a Hilbert space, $E$ is only specified to be a Banach space. It's as you say though: "It may happen that J is not surjective from $E$ onto $E^{**}$ (see Chapters 3 and 4). However, it is convenient to identify $E$ with a subspace of $E^{**}$ using $J$."


To OP, the result cleanly follows by symbol pushing.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed Thanks, I don't have this book, but yes, the same thing works even if $E$ is just a Banach space, all that is needed is the embedding of $E$ into $E''$.